# Firebird Stored Procedure defining tables at runtime and returning values

Tags: select, stored-procedures, firebird

I'm trying to execute  some SQL in a stored procedure, setting the table at runtime, and return the selected value:

```
create or alter procedure TEST3
returns (
    THE_VAR varchar(128))
as
declare variable TABLE_NAME varchar(64);
declare variable STMT varchar(128);
begin
  /* Procedure Text */
  Table_Name = 'users';

  stmt = 'select firstname from ' || :table_name || ' where userid = 2 into :the_var';

  execute statement stmt;

  suspend;
end
```

It results in `Token unknown ......  into`.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use dynamic SQL to assign values to variables in the stored procedure context in this way. That needs to be handled from the `EXECUTE STATEMENT`. You need to change your code to something like:

```
stmt = 'select firstname from ' || :table_name || ' where userid = 2';
execute statement stmt into :the_var;
```

See also the [`EXECUTE STATEMENT` documentation](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-execstmt).